# Installing pgRouting in Windows 7

Tags: pgrouting, installation, windows-7

Can you please help me out in Installing pgRouting in Windows 7 64-bit version.

I have been trying it for days. Since I am completely new to this please provide me the initial requirements and steps in installing pgRouting.

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean that you want to run pgRouting on Windows 7 64-bit OS?
If so, try as follows.

1. Install PostgreSQL 9.1 (**Win x86_32**) and PostGIS (v1.5.x from StackBuilder).
2. Download the pgRouting windows binary(pgRouting-git-sanak-mingw_20120310_pg-9.1(x86).zip) from https://github.com/sanak/pgrouting4w/tree/windows-binary , then extract to "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\" folder. (overwrite "doc", "lib", "share" folder)

If you want to run pgRouting as 64-bit mode (on PostgreSQL 9.1 (**Win x86_64**)),
AFAIK, pgRouting have not supported Windows 64-bit mode yet.

**P.S.**
Short update. Now you can run 64-bit version of pgRouting on Win7 as well - pgRouting binaries built in 64-bit mode could be found by the provided above link on githun (thanks to Sanak!). It was checked with Postgres 9.1/PostGIS 2.0

Comment: thanku sir..i did the steps you mentioned. How can I check whether pgrouting runs on my system?

Comment: Best you try the pgRouting workshop: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/ Just start from chapter 5. You can download the sample data dumps from http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/foss4g2010/workshop/

Comment: @sanak: Thank you for the great work. Is there a plan for PostgreSQL 9.2\PostGIS 2.0.2 compilation too?

Comment: I am planning to create pgrouting-1.x windows binary for PostgreSQL 9.2 in the end of June '13, but if you like new one(pgrouting-2.0), please visit here(http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg92/buildbot/ ). Thanks,

Comment: Best way to check: `SELECT pgr_version();`

Answer (score 3):

Your question was just discussed on the pgRouting mailing list: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/pgrouting-users/2012-May/001142.html

Currently there are no Windows 64bit binaries available, mainly because there were no 64bit Windows binaries available for PostGIS 1.5. Instead most people used 32Bit versions of PostgreSQL/PostGIS/pgRouting.

Comment: Daniel: can you confirm that you are supposed to either replace the folders in the postgresql folder as mentioned in the accepted answer, or as in the mailing list link you provided, you should copy the files from each folder in the binaries download into each corresponding folder in the postgresql directories?

Comment: @DPSSpatial is a 4 years old reply and a lot has changed since then. You can easily install now pgRouting on Windows as explained in the documentation http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/doc/src/installation/installation.html#windows

Comment: @dkastl I guess I'm trying to figure out how to install with an existing installation - maybe better to upgrade to 9.5/2.3 at the same time though...?

Comment: It's difficult to say, if it's better in your case to upgrade. But there have been plenty of improvements, so in general it's good to use the latest release.