# Do postgres 9.1, postgis 2.0 from stackbuilder and pgrouting 1.0.3. work together?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am new to pgrouting and I would like to check if the version I have installed works fine with postgres and postgis.

I have installed postgres 9.1, postgis 2.0 from stackbuilder and pgrouting 1.03.

Any suggestion how I can check if pgrouting works fine?

Comment: First of all could some one please confirm to me if all these versions together works fine or not?

Comment: Did you see another [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26816/installing-pgrouting-in-windows-7)? If not, try it.

Answer (score 1):

According to this blog post http://gregorthemapguy.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/pgrouting-and-postgis-2.html

> We have had very good fortune with running pgRouting 1.0.5 on PostGIS 2.0

I couldn't find information on 1.0.3 version though.

Comment: I've also had success using pgRouting 1.0.5 on PostGIS 2.0/postgres 9.1