# How to install PostGIS 8.4 in Windows 7 64 bit parallel to an existing PostGIS 9.2?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, configuration

PostGIS 9.2 is installed along with OpenGeoSuite using one click setup. But 9.2 doesn't support pgRouting. So I need to install 8.4. I don't how to include binaries and all.

So someone please tell me how to install it in Windows 7 64 bit in detail including what port etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's PostgreSQL 9.2 not PostGIS 9.2, PostGIS is just an add-on for Postgres. You should check this thread for Windows 9.1 packages: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26830/16594. 9.1 is a much better choice than 8.4. Also there is a dev package for 9.2 here: http://www.postgis.net/windows_downloads so probably a stable one will come up soon and it'll be easier to upgrade from 9.1 than from 8.4

Comment: yes it is postgres sorry but I want to install postgres 8.4 only..because pgrouting wont work in new version. so I want to run both the versions.

Comment: it says that shooting star reverse cost issue is still there in the new pgrouting experimental buid version..so I dont want the problem